# Bug in Flickr API or is my understanding incorrect?

Tags: rest, flickr

I'm trying to use the flickr API to get the listing of photos in a pool and so I am using the [getPhotos](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos.html) method.

I'm only passing in the single mandatory argument of the group ID (in my case "1108839@N25"). The response begins by telling me that there are 19 photos in this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <rsp stat="ok">
  <photos page="1" pages="1" perpage="100" total="19">
  ...
```

but [the response](http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos&api_key=727545767ab7bf5a99c1277518796453&group_id=1108839%40N25) only actually contains details of 13 photos. Is this a bug in the flickr API or is there something I'm doing wrong?

If further proof were needed, if the request is structured to only request 1 photo per page, the response says there are 19 pages, but requests for pages past page 13 [are empty](http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos&api_key=727545767ab7bf5a99c1277518796453&group_id=1108839%40N25&per_page=1&page=14)

---

**Update**:
I'm getting closer to the solution...

When I'm not logged in I can see only 13 photos in the pool. However one of the photos not being listed is a photo I submitted and the permissions are set so that it should appear.

This is the photo:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/stolencamerafinder/3592503307/

You should be able to see this when not logged in. It even says it belongs to the pool on the right, but if you try to navigate forwards then backwards in the pool it disappears. Any ideas?

Comment: Might be better to ask in the Flickr API group: http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/

Answer (score 1):

May be the missing images are not public? Only public images are given access.